smbclient is not using my Kerberos token
smbclient is not using my Kerberos token and prompts for the domain user password :
$ echo $KRB5CCNAME
FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_9876543210_T15kdb
$ smbclient --use-kerberos=required -L myRemoteServer.myDOMAIN.myLAN -d 10 --debug-stdout 
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
INFO: Current debug levels:
  all: 10
  tdb: 10
  printdrivers: 10
  lanman: 10
  smb: 10
  rpc_parse: 10
  rpc_srv: 10
  rpc_cli: 10
  passdb: 10
  sam: 10
  auth: 10
  winbind: 10
  vfs: 10
  idmap: 10
  quota: 10
  acls: 10
  locking: 10
  msdfs: 10
  dmapi: 10
  registry: 10
  scavenger: 10
  dns: 10
  ldb: 10
  tevent: 10
  auth_audit: 10
  auth_json_audit: 10
  kerberos: 10
  drs_repl: 10
  smb2: 10
  smb2_credits: 10
  dsdb_audit: 10
  dsdb_json_audit: 10
  dsdb_password_audit: 10
  dsdb_password_json_audit: 10
  dsdb_transaction_audit: 10
  dsdb_transaction_json_audit: 10
  dsdb_group_audit: 10
  dsdb_group_json_audit: 10
Processing section "[global]"
doing parameter workgroup = myDOMAIN
doing parameter client signing = yes
doing parameter client use spnego = yes
lpcfg_do_global_parameter: WARNING: The "client use spnego" option is deprecated
doing parameter kerberos method = secrets and keytab
doing parameter realm = myDOMAIN.myLAN
doing parameter security = ads
doing parameter server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
doing parameter log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
doing parameter max log size = 1000
doing parameter logging = file
doing parameter panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
doing parameter server role = standalone server
doing parameter obey pam restrictions = yes
doing parameter unix password sync = yes
doing parameter passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
doing parameter passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
doing parameter pam password change = yes
doing parameter map to guest = bad user
doing parameter usershare allow guests = yes
pm_process() returned Yes
lp_servicenumber: couldn't find homes
added interface eno1 ip=X.Y.Z.20 bcast=X.Y.Z.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Client started (version 4.19.5-Ubuntu).
Opening cache file at /run/samba/gencache.tdb
tdb(/run/samba/gencache.tdb): tdb_open_ex: could not open file /run/samba/gencache.tdb: Permission denied
gencache_init: Opening user cache file /home/myDOMAIN.myLAN/myUser/.cache/samba/gencache.tdb.
sitename_fetch: No stored sitename for realm 'myDOMAIN.myLAN'
internal_resolve_name: looking up myRemoteServer.myDOMAIN.myLAN#20 (sitename (null))
namecache_fetch: name myRemoteServer.myDOMAIN.myLAN#20 found.
remove_duplicate_addrs2: looking for duplicate address/port pairs
Connecting to T.U.V.W at port 445
socket options: SO_KEEPALIVE=0, SO_REUSEADDR=0, SO_BROADCAST=0, TCP_NODELAY=1, TCP_KEEPCNT=9, TCP_KEEPIDLE=7200, TCP_KEEPINTVL=75, IPTOS_LOWDELAY=0, IPTOS_THROUGHPUT=0, SO_REUSEPORT=0, SO_SNDBUF=46080, SO_RCVBUF=131072, SO_SNDLOWAT=1, SO_RCVLOWAT=1, SO_SNDTIMEO=0, SO_RCVTIMEO=0, TCP_QUICKACK=1, TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT=0, TCP_USER_TIMEOUT=0
 session request ok
 negotiated dialect[SMB3_11] against server[myRemoteServer.myDOMAIN.myLAN]
Password for [myUser@myDOMAIN.myLAN]:
$ 

Here is my /etc/sssd/sssd.conf :
[sssd]
domains = myDOMAIN.myLAN
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/myDOMAIN.myLAN]
default_shell = /bin/bash
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
cache_credentials = True
krb5_realm = myDOMAIN.myLAN
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
id_provider = ad
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
ad_domain = myDOMAIN.myLAN
use_fully_qualified_names = True
ldap_id_mapping = True
access_provider = ad

And my /etc/krb5.conf :

[libdefaults]
udp_preference_limit = 0
default_realm = myDOMAIN.myLAN
renew_lifetime = 7d

Can you help me ?
